# Ubuntu broken after update (black screen)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

So a couple of days ago I got this notification new ubuntu version blah update.
I was downloading the update and while that happened I opended chrome for a second, the just after launching chrome I got an error screen: "unknown error" on chrome and in my desktop, which means both of them crashed I guess. Inmediatly after that my laptop turned off and won't load ubuntu anymore, when I boot, I get the usual grub, the HP logo appears on screen, and then I get a black screen with this "_" thing on the top left corner showing and dissapearing, and I can't do anything but shut down my laptop by pressing the power button

I still got the grub and recovery mode, I have tried to reinstall packages with dpkg, update the grub, modify the "quiet splash" to "nosetmode" and even delete both those lines, and still got the same error. Also tried fsck.

My device is: HP Pavilion - 14-bf004ns, Intel Core i5-7200U, 8 GB DDR4-2133 SDRAM (1 x 8 GB), Intel HD Graphics 620, 1TB of SSD memory, where I made a partition for ubuntu.

I have thought about re-flashing ubuntu, since I still got the BIOS and the chance of booting from EFI file and external Hard Drive, but if there's any other option to this I'll be very thankfull to hear it.
Thanks!

Comment: I edited the post and gave every detail I could, I have also tried sudo apt-get upgrade, update and install, and nothing changed.

Comment: At boot, go into BIOS Setup (not GRUB). Is your SSD detected by BIOS? Is the SSD offered as a boot option?

Comment: Yes it is, it's where windows and Ubuntu are installed with a partition, but I think my problem is something related with desktop, which doesn't show up at boot.      I can login using my terminal, I've tried to download different desktop versions but there always seems to be a problem with sudo apt